# Why is my server program not recieving the command?

Tags: java

Server code:

```
 try{
  ServerSocket guard=new ServerSocket(6600);
  StackCalculator SC=new StackCalculator();
   while(true){
    SC.currentSocket=guard.accept();
    Socket currentSocket;
    Scanner s=new Scanner(currentSocket.getInputStream());
    PrintWriter pw=new PrintWriter(currentSocket.getOutputStream());
    String request=s.nextLine();
    int num=Integer.parseInt(s.nextLine());
    int reply=PerformCalculation(request,num);//method to perform calculation
    pw.println(reply);
    pw.flush();
 }
```

Client Code:

```
  try{
    Socket sc=new Socket("localhost",6600);
    Scanner s=new Scanner(sc.getInputStream());
    PrintWriter pw=new PrintWriter(sc.getOutputStream());
    pw.print("ROOT 4");
    pw.flush();

    String response=s.nextLine();

    System.out.println(response);
    pw.close();
    sc.close();
  }
```

This is a part of the code. Client is connecting to server and is also passing the request. But server is not reading it from Scanner.

Comment: Possibly the obvious syntax errors in the server code are tripping you up.  Compile the code first before pasting it here.

Comment: Your client is doing `print` but not `println`, so no newline sequence is being sent.  Your server uses `nextLine()` (twice—did you intend to read two lines?), which means it must receive a newline sequence before it will see the command.

Answer (score 0):

You never  even initialize "currentSocket", which means you should get a NullPointerException when trying to do: "currentSocker.getInputStream()", because you performed the guard.accept() on SC.currentSocket - which IS NOT currentSocket.

Additionally as the commentors have suggested, you are never sending a whole line from the server as you are calling:

```
pw.print("ROOT 4");
pw.flush();
```

where you should call

```
pw.println("ROOT 4");
pw.flush();
```

And you are also reading multiple lines on the server - which seems like a bug to me.

Answer (score 0):

there were sevral things wrong on both client and server.you are reffering to  `Socket currentSocket;`  which was never initialized. and on the server code you are accepting 2 inputs from client bt client is only giving one input.i fixed both server side and client side code you might wanna give  it a try.

```
while(true){

    Socket currentSocket =  guard.accept();
    Scanner s=new Scanner(currentSocket.getInputStream());
    PrintWriter pw=new PrintWriter(currentSocket.getOutputStream());
    String request=s.nextLine(); //****accepting first input 
    int num=Integer.parseInt(s.nextLine()); //****accepting second input program is stuck here
    int reply=PerformCalculation(request,num);//method to perform calculation
    pw.println(reply);
    pw.flush();
 }
```

//client code

```
 try{
    Socket sc=new Socket("localhost",6600);
    Scanner s=new Scanner(sc.getInputStream());
    PrintWriter pw=new PrintWriter(sc.getOutputStream());
    pw.println("ROOT 4"); //giving out the first input
    pw.println("123");//giving out the second input - should be a number server is expecting a int.
    pw.flush();

    String response=s.nextLine();
    System.out.println(response);

    pw.close();
    sc.close();
  }
```